# PHP Split string output up randomly insert into array

Tags: php

I am trying to find the best way to split a string up randomly.

Example :

```
$variable1 = "this_is_the_string_contents";
```

The output I am trying to achieve is this.

```
"is"
"this"
"ents"
"cont"
"_"
etc
etc
```

What is the best way to do this. I have no idea what PHP function(s) would be most suited to the task I have been looking at a mix of, foreach(), rand() etc.

Comment: Maybe try using [chunk_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) and ``rand``, ``strlen`` and friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will break a string down into an array of random length substrings.

```
$l = strlen($variable1);
$i = 0;                                       // holds the current string position

while ($i < $l) {
    $r = rand(1, $l - $i);                    // get a random length for the next substring
    $chunks[] = substr($variable1, $i, $r);   // add the substring to the array
    $i += $r;                                 // increment $i by the substring length
}
```

This will be totally random, so you could end up with an array like

```
["this_is_the_string_content","s"]
```

instead of the more evenly distributed example you showed. If you want to avoid that, you could "de-randomize" the random length part a bit.

```
if ($l - $i > $i) {
    $r = rand(1, ($l - $i) / 2);
} else {
    $r = rand(1, $l - $i);        
}
```

That will prevent substrings from consuming more than half of the string, until half of the string is gone.

---

After you have the array of substrings, you can randomize it as well with

```
shuffle($chunks);
```

Comment: Thank's for the help I marked your answer as the solution :) Also @EdCottrell your answer before it was removed this website is super useful https://3v4l.org/cRicH So thanks also for sharing a demo link.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$str = "this_is_the_string_contents";
$stringPiece = str_split($str, 4); //put in whatever number here for chunk size
print_r($stringPiece);
```

You can use rand() to generate a random number for chunk size if you wish. Depending on what you are trying to do, it might be worth considering removing spaces/underscores.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with the generator. The following code splits the string into a random string of between one and five characters in length.

```php
<?php

$mystring = 'abcdefghchijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789';

function chunks($string, int $chunk = 5) {
    while (strlen($string) > $chunk) {
        $len = rand(1, $chunk);
        yield substr($string, 0, $len);
        $string = substr($string, $len);
    }
    yield $string; // end of the string
}

$output = iterator_to_array(chunks($mystring, 10));
var_dump($output);
```

Check [demo code](https://3v4l.org/JriTS)